# Titanium/ Alloy: Add event listener to a window

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I have the following code in **index.js**:

```
var win = Alloy.createController('foo').getView();
win.open();
win.addEventListener('exampleEvent', function () {
    Ti.API.info('Event Run!'); // does not seem to run
});
```

on **foo.js** I have the following:

```
function runEvent() {
    $.trigger('exampleEvent');
    $.getView().close();
}

// execute runEvent() somewhere later
```

However, the function in the event listener does not seem to run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a point that custom events can only be added on a controller, not on the view.

```
var win = Alloy.createController('foo').getView();
```

In this line, you are holding the view by using **getView()** in **win** variable.

***Now, it should be like this:***

```
var win = Alloy.createController('foo');

win.on('exampleEvent', function () {
    Ti.API.info('Event Run!'); // it will run now as you have added custom event on controller (means $ in .js file) itself.
});

// now you can get the top-most view (which is a window in this case) and can further use open() method on window
win.getView().open();
```

***foo.js will remain same:***

```
function runEvent() {
    $.trigger('exampleEvent');
    $.getView().close();
}

// execute runEvent() somewhere later
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using

```
var controller = Alloy.createController('myController');
controller.addEventListener("customEvent",function(){});
```

I've been smacking my head for the last hour...

on top of what @PrashantSaini presented, there s no addEventListener on controller objects, controllers have the `on` function, so it should be :

```
controller.on("customEvent",function(){});
```

**update**

My answer is a heads up for the fact that there no addeventlistener on controller object.

Comment: I don't see how that is any different to @Prashant Sainj answer